# SQL update query is not working in Java program

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am trying to update record in MySQL table. But when I execute it, it is not reflecting changes. No error or exceptions occurred. I tried with con.commit() and con.setAutoCommit(false) but no changes reflected. Only Home button is displayed on screen and even alerts in my program not displayed.

This is editnew.jsp

```html
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<input type="hidden" value="update" name="update"/>
<input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</td>
</tr>
```

This is my editprocess.jsp code

```html
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>editprocess jsp Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
String z_id = request.getParameter("zid");
String first_Name = request.getParameter("firstname");
String last_Name = request.getParameter("lastname");
String mail_i_d = request.getParameter("mailid");
String d_iv = request.getParameter("division");
String de_pt = request.getParameter("department");

...
            
String iss_uer = request.getParameter("issuer");
String sta_tus = request.getParameter("status");
String file_Name = "";
String folder_Name = "allfiles";
String pa_th = folder_Name + File.separator + file_Name;
Timestamp add_ed_date = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
if(request.getParameter("update") != null){
  Connection con = null;
  PreparedStatement ps = null;
  try{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     con =             DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms","root","");
     String sql = "update dmsfiles set firstname=?,lastname=?,mailid=?,division=?,department=?,costcentercode=?,document_number=?,document_name=?,document_type=?,document_category=?,document_classification=?,authorised_by=?,fromdate=?,todate=?,document_level=?,document_general=?,serial_number=?,revision_number=?,issuer=?,status=?,filename=?,path=?,added_date=? where document_name='"+doc_Name+"'"; 
     ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
     // ps.setString(1,z_id);
     ps.setString(1,first_Name);
     ps.setString(2,last_Name);
     ps.setString(3,mail_i_d);
     ps.setString(4,d_iv);
     ps.setString(5,de_pt);
     ps.setString(6,cost_centercode);
     ps.setString(7,doc_num);
     ps.setString(8,doc_Name);
     ps.setString(9,doc_Type);
     ps.setString(10,doc_Category);
     ps.setString(11,doc_classification);
     ps.setString(12,authorised_by);
     ps.setString(13,from_date);
     ps.setString(14,to_date);
     ps.setString(15,document_level);
     ps.setString(16,document_general);
     ps.setString(17,serial_number);
     ps.setString(18,revision_number);
     ps.setString(19,iss_uer);
     ps.setString(20,sta_tus);
     ps.setString(21,file_Name);
     ps.setString(22,pa_th);
     ps.setTimestamp(23, add_ed_date);
     int i = ps.executeUpdate(sql);
     con.commit();
     if(i > 0)
     {
       out.println("alert('Record Updated Successfully');");
     }
     else
     {
       out.println("alert('There is a problem in updating Record.');");
     }
    }
    catch(SQLException sql)
    {
     sql.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
%>
<a href="home.jsp" class="btn btn-info">Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need to pass `sql` here-> `ps.executeUpdate(sql);` it should simply be `ps.executeUpdate();` change this and check onces.

Comment: @Swati I tried as you said but didn't worked.

Comment: In where clause also you have `document_name` and in your query part also you have `document_name` i.e : `document_name=?` ..why ? Also does your if statement gets executed or not ? does  `if(request.getParameter("update") != null){`  returns true or not ? Debug your code line by line and check where it fails .

Comment: I have 3 records with same "zid" so if I write "zid" in where clause instead of document_name then all 3 records will update. So that I have used document_name in where clause

Comment: So in `editnew.jsp` you are even updating your `document_name` ? how will the query come to know which rows has to be updated? You need to have one unique column in your table i.e `primary key` that will not get changed .and you can use that `column` to update your `row`.

Comment: @Swati I have two tables in my database first is dmsmembers and second is dmsfiles. "zid" is the primary key for dmsmembers table and "document_name" is primary key for dmsfiles. I have set document_name as primary key now for dmsfiles table. before this there was no primary key for dmsfiles table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207819/discussion-between-swati-and-priya-dhanba).

Comment: @Swati please move to discussion chat